# viewing xaml loaded in the browser

Tags: silverlight

Is there any way to view XAML tree loaded into a browser?

We are using one proprietary component, that loads xaml dynamically (`Application.GetResourceStream`), and there seems to be a problem with what it loads. How do I get a glimpse of xaml loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just wrapping the Stream returned by `Application.GetResourceStream` in a `StreamReader` to inspect the XAML?

Beyond that, [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy) is a great tool for inspecting the UI at runtime -- it lets you navigate the full visual tree and will even highlight what you've selected with a red rectangle inside the app.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. Been looking for just a simple Silverlight DOM browser and this tool is just that! The free edition (not the trial, the actual base free edition) has a DOM browser. Perfect for looking up Name or AutomationId for automating Silverlight apps.